# See if WCHAR* is substring of WCHAR in C

Tags: c, string, windows, unicode, unicode-string

I am using the Windows function `CreateToolhelp32snapshot` to enumerate running processes on my machine. The `pe32.szeFileName` field it returns is a `WCHAR`, and this is the executable's name.

I want to compare each executable name to a long array of executables I produce, like so:

```
WCHAR* processNames[numProcesses] = { "word", "excel", "outlook, ...}
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how to check if **any element of this processNames array is a substring** of the `WCHAR` returned from `pe32.szeFilename`.

I know `wcsstr` would work if I was dealing with two `const wchar_t *` strings. How can I compare the `WCHAR`returned by `pe32.szeFilename` with each element of an array of strings? Specifically, I want to see if any string in the array (any kind of format is fine) is a substring of the `WCHAR`.

**EDIT:** My current loop:

```
do {

    wprintf(L"Process name: %s\n", pe32.szExeFile);
    for (int i = 0; i < numProcesses; ++i) {
        if (wcsstr(pe32.szExeFile, processNames[i])) {
            // Found it
            wprintf("%s", pe32.szExeFile);

        }
    }

} while (Process32Next(hProcessSnap, &pe32));
```

Comment: That field is an array of characters, not a single character.

Comment: Please include the `for` loop you have now, so we can see what you tried, and describe what you specifically need help with.

Comment: @RaymondChen I specifically want to see if any string in an array of strings  I declare (I don't care the format) is a substring of any `pe32.szExeFile`, which is a `WCHAR`

Comment: @RetiredNinja Could you clarify? Do you know how I can find a substring from `pe32.szExeFile` if I have an array of strings I want to check against it?

Comment: The part of the code you've posted looks fine.  What goes wrong?  Are there any compiler warnings?  Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: ... note that this is a case-sensitive search, so if the process name is `WINWORD.EXE` then `word` won't be found as a substring, it would have to be `WORD`.  You might need to call `_wcslwr` to convert the process name to lowercase if you need a case-insensitive search.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I never enter the `if` statement in this case. All process names are lower case. I imagine this doesn't work becuase I'm passing a `WCHAR` and `WCHAR*` as arguments, and the `wcsstr` function wants two `const wchar_t*`

Comment: No, you're passing two `wchar_t *` because the array name is automatically converted to a pointer.  However, the first line of code (right near the top of the post) shouldn't compile, since you're assigning narrow strings to a wide string pointer.  Are you sure you posted that correctly?

Comment: ... also one of the `wprintf` lines has the wrong string type.  Is this your real code?

Comment: are you look for this function - [`RtlIsNameInExpression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff546850(v=vs.85).aspx) ? or `wcsstr` is enough for you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question tagged with `unicode`, so I suppose, you should try to change all literals' declaration to `L"characters"`, e.g.:

```
WCHAR* processNames[numProcesses] = { L"word", L"excel", L"outlook", ...}
```

then check that appropriate unicode functions are used, e.g. `UNICODE` is defined or function names with `W` used:

```
Process32FirstW(hProcessSnap, &pe32);
. . . 
Process32NextW(hProcessSnap, &pe32);
```

and finally (start from that one, perhaps this allows you to see the result of condition of `if`), use `L"%s"` for `wprintf`:

```
wprintf(L"%s", pe32.szExeFile);
```

**UPDATE:**

Just to check behavior of `wprintf` I wrote a small piece of code (Visual Studio 2013 was used), so result of

```cpp
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(void)
{
    WCHAR* procName = L"excel";

    WCHAR* processNames[3] = { L"word", L"excel", L"outlook" };

    wprintf(L"Process name: %s\n", procName);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
       if (wcsstr(procName, processNames[i])) {
           wprintf("%s", procName);
       }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

is

> Process name: excel

(i.e. looks like `if` has false condition),

but code (only one `L` added for `wprintf` inside loop)

```cpp
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(void)
{
    WCHAR* procName = L"excel";

    WCHAR* processNames[3] = { L"word", L"excel", L"outlook" };

    wprintf(L"Process name: %s\n", procName);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
       if (wcsstr(procName, processNames[i])) {
           wprintf(L"%s", procName);
       }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

shows

> Process name: excel
>
> excel

Comment: Re "*then use appropriate unicode functions names*", ...if they're not already. After all, `Process32First` maps to `Process32FirstW` instead of `Process32FirstA` if `UNICODE` is defined. It's simpler to define `UNICODE` and keep using the same macros as before (e.g. `Process32First`).

Comment: @ikegami Good clarification! Updated

Comment: one note - if we want case insensitive search substring - need first call `_wcslwr(pe32.szExeFile)` before `wcsstr`

Comment: Wow.  Do you not at least get a compiler warning when passing `wprintf` the wrong sort of format string?